# Is there something opposite to \n that could bring me back to previous line?

Tags: c

So I am wondering is there something that could bring me back to the first line, because if I type printf("\n") 10 times, how can I come back to first line again?

Comment: There is no common ascii-code for that, but terminal-specific escape sequences. You can use a library like ncurses, which provides an abstract interface for such actions for a multitude of common terminals (and terminal emulations)

Comment: "\b" is a backspace, but not all consoles support it. You may need to use a library like curses, or look into ANSII escape codes.

Comment: Backspace may not go back beyond the start of the line. Some consoles have a limited buffer of what has scrolled off the top, but not all. Easiest is to use a console library, or keep your own copy of what is on display.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge you can't return to the first line, because once you have printed something on the console (where you see output) it is there.

Think of it like a river once you have poured some water to the river you can't take that water now.

I hope this helped you